# Shell scripting shell inside shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to connect to different shells (csh, ksh etc.,) and execute command inside each switched shell.

Following is the sample program which reflects my intention:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $SHELL
csh
echo $SHELL
exit
ksh
echo $SHELL
exit
```

Since, i am not well versed with Shell scripting need a pointer on how to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute only one single command, you can use the `-c` option

```
csh -c 'echo $SHELL'
ksh -c 'echo $SHELL'
```

If you want to execute several commands, or even a whole script in a child-shell, you can use the here-document feature of bash and use the `-s` (read commands from `stdin`) on the child shells:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is bash"

csh -s <<- EOF
    echo "here go the commands for csh"
    echo "and another one..."
EOF
echo "this is bash again"
ksh -s <<- EOF
    echo "and now, we're in ksh"
EOF
```

Note that you can't easily check the shell you are in by `echo $SHELL`, because the parent shell **expands** this variable to the text `/././bash`. If you want to be sure that the child shell works, you should check if a shell-specific syntax is working or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for the timely help, thanks to others who gave similar solutions

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the command line options provided by each shell to run a snippet of code.

For example, for `bash` use the `-c` option:

```
bash -c $code
bash -c 'echo hello'
```

`zsh` and `fish` also use the `-c` option.

Other shells will state the options they use in their man pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `-c` command line option if you want to pass commands on bash startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
# We are in bash already ...
echo $SHELL

csh -c 'echo $SHELL'
ksh -c 'echo $SHELL'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arbitrary complex scripts to a shell, using the `-c` option, as in

```
sh -c 'echo This is the Bourne shell.'
```

You will save you a lot of headaches related to quotes and variable expansion if you wrap the call in a function reading the script on *stdin* as:

```
execute_with_ksh()
{
  local script
  script=$(cat)
  ksh -c "${script}"
}

prepare_complicated_script()
{
   # Write shell script on stdout,
   #  for instance by cat-ting a here-document.
   cat <<'EOF'
echo ${SHELL}
EOF 
}

prepare_complicated_script | execute_with_ksh
```

The advantage of this method is that it easy to insert a tee in the pipe or to break the pipe to control the script being passed to the shell.

If you want to execute the script on a remote host through **ssh** you should consider encode your script in base 64 to transmit it safely to the remote shell.

Comment: Looks like I'm missing something. What is the meaning of `$configfile` ? How is it related to this question?

Comment: @hek2mgl Well, I do not know! :) The new example is maybe better.